# Averaging one column based on date interval from a different data.frame in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, date

I have two `data.frame`.

In DF1, I have ID-level data with two date columns, *Date1* and *Date2*, and state and county columns. IDs will repeat if they have different *Date1* but they will always have the same *Date2*.

In DF2, I have one date column (that has multiple entries per date/state/county combo because data was collected at several times in one day), state, county, and variable X that I'm interested in.

I would like to create a separate column in DF1 that averages X for each person, over the time interval of Date1 to Date2, for the specific county and state.

There are more county/state combos in DF2 than in DF1.

Based on a previous question someone asked, I tried the following and got an error stating that there are a different number of factors in the state columns in DF1 vs DF2:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(DF1)){
DF1$MeanX[i]<-mean(DF2$X[which(DF2$State==DF1$State[i] &
                            DF2$County==DF1$County[i] &
                            DF2$Date>=DF1$Date1[i] &
                            DF2$Date<=DF1$Date2[i])])
}
```

Here is condensed version of DF1:

```
structure(list(ID = c(10L, 1003L, 1007L, 1007L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
1011L, 1015L, 1016L), Date1 = structure(c(16724, 17317, 16919, 
17316, 17053, 17056, 17427, 16778, 17091, 17317), class = "Date"), 
Date2 = structure(c(16825, 17444, 17371, 17371, 17548, 17548, 
17548, 16839, 17378, 17378), class = "Date"), State = structure(c(8L, 
4L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 4L, 4L, 23L), .Label = c("", 
"Alabama", "Arizona", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", 
"District Of Columbia", "Florida", "Georgia", "Illinois", 
"Kansas", "Kentucky", "Maryland", "Mississippi", "Missouri", 
"Nebraska", "Nevada", "New York", "North Carolina", "Ohio", 
"Oklahoma", "Rhode Island", "Texas", "Virginia", "Washington"
), class = "factor"), County = structure(c(16L, 48L, 42L, 
42L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 48L, 48L, 37L), .Label = c("", "Anne Arundel", 
"Arlington", "Bay", "Bell", "Bexar", "Camden", "Chatham", 
"Chattahoochee", "Christian", "Clark", "Comanche", "Craven", 
"Cumberland", "District Of Columbia", "Duval", "El Paso", 
"Escambia", "Fairfax", "Geary", "Greene", "Hampton City", 
"Hardin", "Harrison", "Hillsborough", "Hinds", "Houston", 
"Island", "Kitsap", "Lake", "Liberty", "Montgomery", "New London", 
"Newport", "Newport News", "Norfolk City", "Nueces", "Okaloosa", 
"Onslow", "Orange", "Pierce", "Portsmouth", "Prince George's", 
"Prince William", "Pulaski", "Richmond", "San Bernadino", 
"San Diego", "Sarpy", "Solano", "Tom Green", "Virginia Beach City", 
"Yuma"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here's is a condensed version of DF2 (this doesn't include every state/county combo because there are too many, but just to see the structure):

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(16441, 16447, 16453, 16459, 
16465, 16471, 16477, 16483, 16489, 16495), class = "Date"), X = c(8L, 
8L, 10L, 14L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 8L, 17L, 17L), State = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Alabama", "Alaska", 
"Arizona", "California", "Colorado", "District Of Columbia", 
"Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Louisiana", "Maryland", "Mississippi", 
"Nevada", "New Mexico", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", 
"Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Virginia"), class = "factor"), 
County = structure(c(20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L), .Label = c("Anchorage ", "Anne Arundel", "Bernalillo", 
"Bexar", "Bossier", "Brevard", "Clark", "Cumberland", "Davis", 
"District of Columbia", "Duval", "El Paso", "Fairfax", "Greene", 
"Hampton City", "Hillsborough", "Hinds", "Honolulu", "Kings", 
"Madison", "Monterey", "Montgomery", "Norfolk City", "Nueces", 
"Okaloosa", "Pima", "Prince George's", "Richmond", "San Bernardino", 
"San Diego", "Santa Barbara", "Shelby", "Solano", "Tarrant", 
"Ventura", "Ward", "Yuma"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Can someone adjust my loop to average X (from DF2) between *Date1* to *Date2* (from DF1) by county and state (matching DF1 to DF2)?

Comment: Just convert your factor variables into character ones by using `as.character()` inside your loop. Like ; `as.character(DF2$State)==as.character(DF1$State)[i]`     and                              `as.character(DF2$County)==  as.character(DF1$County)[i]` . Or you can prefer to convert them at the beginning like `DF2$State <- as.character(DF2$State)`  etc.

Comment: @maydin thank you! Works perfectly!